# Тормоза в QListView

Tags: c++, qt

Краткий экскурс. Существует программа учета клиентов, там происходит работа с базой данных клиентов, добавление, удаление заметок, прочее. В общем по сути красивая оболочка по работе с базой данных.

Проблема в следующем. Раньше стоял QListWidget, заполнял его именами компаний из базы данных. Всё было красиво, правильно, но, зараза, медленно. При тестировании на 5000 записей наблюдались тормоза, к тому же при удалении/добавлении новой компании в программе, приходилось изредка обновлять этот ListWidget, грубо говоря синхронизировать его с базой данных - очищать его и выводить все элементы по новой, что, опять же, вызывало зависания и тормоза. Решил уйти от ListWidget'a в сторону ListView и моделей. Воспользовался моделью QSqlQueryModel, заполняю её путем ->setQuery, закидываю в ListView, весь нужный мне функционал сделал, путем проб и ошибок вернул всю функциональность, которая существовала с ListWidget, но опять, зараза, медленно, но теперь в другом. Просто стало лагать приложение, лагает масштабирование окна, лагает скролбар (объекты ведь сразу все не показываются, они подгружаются по мере скролла вниз), и само ощущение от работы с программой стало еще более паршивое. Подскажите, кто с подобными задачами сталкивался, какое решение вы можете предложить?

Comment: надо бенчмаркать, может Вы на каждый чих перезагружаете с базы все. или записи по одной тяните, или по ключам вытягиваете зависимые данные поштучно. В целом, куча причин.

Comment: отказ от  qt ...

Comment: слишком толсто. слишком. Даже на javascript можно писать вполне быстрые приложения, если руки ровные.

Comment: не видя кода никто не подскажет. где-то ваш косяк